# Proving that $\arg(w)\in\left(\frac{-3\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having some trouble with the following exercise:

> Let $z_1=-3+2i$, $z_2=-1+2i$ and $z_3=2-i$. Let $$w=\frac{z_1\cdot z_2}{z_3}$$
> Show that the following is true without using a calculator: $$|w|=\sqrt{13}\ \ \wedge\ \  \arg(w)\in\left(\frac{-3\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

I was able to show that $|w|=\sqrt{13}$ very easily but I'm having some trouble with the second part. I tried using the fact that $\arg(w)=\arg(z_1)+\arg(z_2)-\arg(z_3)$ but I have no idea how to compute this without a calculator. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to evade the complex-number multiplications if we note the angles between the vectors representing the given numbers.  If we "extract" the modulus of each number to write it as $ \ z \ = \ |z|·\widehat{z} \ \ , \ $  the second factor being a number of unit modulus with the "direction" $ \ \arg z \ \ . \ $  Our numbers are then
$$ z_1 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{13} · \widehat{z_1} \ \ \ , \ \ \ z_2 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{5} · \widehat{z_2} \ \ \ , \ \ \ z_3 \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{5} · \widehat{z_3} \ \ . $$
So, as you found,
$$ \frac{z_1 \  z_2}{z_3} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sqrt{13} \ · \ \sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{5}} · \ \  \widehat{u}   \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left| \frac{z_1  \ z_2}{z_3} \right| \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{13} \ \ , \ $$
since the "quotient" $ \ \widehat{u} \ $ of the numbers of unit modulus is itself of unit modulus.  (We will not actually concern ourselves with these numbers, other than in employing them diagrammatically.)

For what follows, we will work with $ \ z_3^{-1} \ = \ \frac{\overline{z_3}}{5} \ = \ \frac{2 \ +  \ i}{5} \ = \ \frac{1}{\sqrt5} · \widehat{z_3^{-1}} \ \ . \ $  We observe that the angle between  $ \ z_2 \ = \ -1 + 2i \ $ and $ \ z_3^{-1} \ = \ \frac{1}{5} · (2 + i) \ \ , \ $ is $ \  \pi / 2  \ $  since $ \ \tan (\arg z_2) \ = \ \frac{2}{-1} \ $ and $ \ \tan (\arg z_3^{-1}) \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \ . \ $    [Alternatively, we can say that  a vector $ \ \langle a \ , \ b \rangle \ $ rotated counter-clockwise by $ \  \pi / 2  \ $ is transformed to $ \ \langle -b \ , \ a \rangle \ \ , \ $ or note that $ \ \mathfrak{Re}(z_2 \ \overline{z_3^{-1}} ) \ = \ 0 \ \ . \ ] \ $  We will call $ \ \alpha \ = \ \pi - \arg z_1 \ $ and  $ \ \beta \ = \ \arg z_3^{-1} \  : \ $ we have said that $ \ \tan  \beta  \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ \  $ and we see that $ \ \tan (\arg z_1) \ = \ \frac{2}{-3} \ \ , \ $ so $ \ \alpha \ $ is a larger angle than $ \ \beta \ $ [see graph below].

We determine from this that $ \ \arg z_2 \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} + \beta \ $ and therefore $ \ \arg (z_2 \  z_3^{-1}) \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} + \beta + \beta \ = \ \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\beta \ \ . \ $  As mentioned above, rotating $ \ z_1 \ = \ -3 + 2i \ $ counter-clockwise by $ \ \pi/2 \ $ takes it to $ \ v \ = \ -2 - 3i \ \ ; \ $ as the angle from $ \ z_1 \ $ counter-clockwise to the negative $ \ \mathfrak{Re} \ $ axis is $ \ \alpha \ \ , \ $ the angle from $ \ v \ $ counter-clockwise to the negative $ \ \mathfrak{Im} \ $ axis is likewise $ \ \alpha \ \ , \ $ thus $ \ \arg v \ = \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} - \alpha \ = \ -\left( \ \frac{\pi}{2} + \alpha  \ \right) \ \ . \ $  By comparison,
$$ \arg (z_1 \ z_2 \  z_3^{-1}) \ \ = \ \ \arg w \ \ = \ \ ( \ \pi \ - \ \alpha \ ) \ + \ ( \ \frac{\pi}{2} + 2\beta \ ) \ \ = \ \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} \ + \ ( \ 2 \beta \ - \ \alpha \ ) \ \ . $$

The number $ \ v \ $ is plainly in the third quadrant; it remains to determine "on which side" of $ \ \theta \ = \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} \ $ our quotient $ \ w \ $ lies.  Applying the "double-angle formula" for tangent, we obtain
$$ \tan (2 \beta) \ \ = \ \ \frac{2 · \tan \beta}{1 \ - \ \tan^2 \beta} \ \ = \ \ = \ \ \frac{2 · \frac12}{1 \ - \ \left[\frac12 \right]^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac43 \ \ .  $$
We conclude that $ \ 2 \ \beta \ > \ \alpha \ \ , \ $ so $ \ w \ $ is in the *fourth* quadrant.  Further,
$$ \tan (2 \beta \ - \ \alpha ) \ \ = \ \ \frac{\tan (2 \beta) \ - \ \tan \alpha}{1 \ + \ \tan (2 \beta) · \tan \alpha} \ \ = \ \ = \ \ \frac{\frac43 - \frac23}{1 \ + \  \frac43 · \frac23} \ \ = \ \ \frac{2/3}{17/9} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6}{17} \ \ .  $$
Hence, $ \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} \ < \ \frac{3 \pi}{2} \ + \ ( \ 2 \beta \ - \ \alpha \ ) \ < \ \frac{3 \pi}{2}  +  \frac{\pi}{4} \ \  $ or $ \ \ -\frac{\pi}{2} \ < \ \arg w \ < \ -\frac{\pi}{4} \ \ . \ $

Interpreted as an angle in the fourth quadrant, the result $ \tan (\arg w) \ = \ -\frac{17}{6} \ \ $ is consistent with the value $ \ \frac{z_1 \  z_2}{z_3} \ = \ \frac15·(6 \ - \ 17i) \ $ shown by **user2661923**.  (I suspect that there was a typo or unadjusted revision in the problem statement:  it seems likely to me that it was intended that $ \ z_1 \ = \ \mathbf{-2 + 3i} \ \ , \ $ which would have produced an argument in the designated interval.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Let $z_1=-3+2i$, $z_2=-1+2i$ and $z_3=2-i$. Let $$w=\frac{z_1\cdot z_2}{z_3}$$
> Show that the following is true without using a calculator: $$|w|=\sqrt{13}\ \ \wedge\ \  \arg(w)\in\left(\frac{-3\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

Alternative approach:

Polar coordinates are unnecessary.  For any non-zero complex number $z$, the argument of $z$ will be in the range

$$\left(\frac{-3\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

if and only if each of the following conditions are met:

- Both the real and imaginary components of $z$ are negative.
- The absolute value of the real component is smaller than the absolute value of the imaginary component.

The above conclusion is *inspired* by examining (in $\Bbb{R^2}$) the region, in the $3$rd quadrant, between the $y$-axis, and the line $y = x.$

Since explicit multiplication is required, I will start with $z_3$.

$$\frac{1}{z_3} = \frac{1}{2-i} \times \frac{2+i}{2+i} = \frac{2+i}{5}.$$

Also,

$$z_1 \times z_2 = (-3 + 2i) \times (-1 + 2i) = (-1 - 8i).$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{z_1 \times z_2}{z_3} = (-1 - 8i) \times \frac{2+i}{5} = \frac{6 - 17i}{5}. \tag1 $$

Here, it is easy to compute:

$$\left|\frac{6 - 17i}{5}\right| = \sqrt{\frac{6^2 + 17^2}{5^2}} = \sqrt{13}.$$

However, the *relative* real and imaginary components shown in the numerator of the RHS of (1) above, do not satisfy the conditions necessary for the argument of the complex number to be in $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{-3\pi}{4},-\frac{\pi}{2}\right).~$

Instead, you have virtually the same conditions being satisfied except that the real component is positive rather than negative.  Therefore, [within a modulus of $(2\pi)$], the argument is between $~\displaystyle \left(\frac{-\pi}{2},-\frac{\pi}{4}\right).~$

That is, the real component is positive and the imaginary component is negative.  Therefore, the complex number is in the $4$th quadrant.  Further, the absolute value of the real component is less than the absolute value of the imaginary component.

So, the conclusion is reached by examining, in $\Bbb{R^2}$, the region in the $4$th quadrant between the $y$-axis and the line $y = -x.$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can rewrite each $z_i$ by $$ z_i=(|z_i|)\dfrac{z_i}{|z_i|}$$ and get the polar form

So for instance :

$$z_1=\sqrt{13}\left(\dfrac{-3+2i}{\sqrt{13}}\right) $$

And writing $e^{i\theta_1}=\dfrac{-3+2i}{\sqrt{13}}$, you can find boundary for $\theta_1$. And so on for the others. Is that clear ?

Comment: How can I find such boundary ?

Comment: By looking at the value of $cos$ because here $\dfrac{-3}{\sqrt{13}}=cos(\theta)$ so you can find boundary on $\theta$ making a drawing is helpful.